# how to query a JSON document when there are periods in the class names?

Tags: c#, json

I'm using C# and receiving a JSON document that gets stored in a dynamic object type.  I'm trying to pull data from the JSON into my variable as such:

```
myValue = data.resource.fields.System.ChangedDate.newValue
```

data is the name of my dynamic object.

the problem is that the document is constructed as follows:

```
resource 
  fields
    System.ChangedDate
      newValue
```

so "System.ChangedDate" has a period in the class name which makes C# think they are two separate classes.

Comment: Does this work? `myValue = data.resource.fields["System.ChangedDate"].newValue`

Comment: Thanks but no, error by the first [

Comment: Any chance you might be able to figure out what the error is? Are you using Newtonsoft.Json, or something else?

Comment: Wait, Ed was right, I had an extra period.  It works.  Thanks @EdPlunkett

Comment: ED IS ALWAYS RIGHT. Except usually. But hey, close enough.

Comment: Indeed.  :) but how can I vote if you just commented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Newtonsoft.Json, this should work:

```
myValue = data.resource.fields["System.ChangedDate"].newValue;
```